# Hive hql : aggregating into MAP datatype

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a table called graph_table with 2 columns

```
node_id INT  
neighbour_id INT
```

I need to run the following select query

```
SELECT node_id, aggregater_func( neighbour_id ) as neighbourhood  FROM graph_table GROUP BY node_id
```

aggregater_func  aggregates neighbours into a `MAP <INT(neighbour_id), INT(frequency)>`

What should be this aggregater_func ?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do this with native HQL.

But using PrestoDB from Facebook, you can get advantage of histogram function

From https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html:

> histogram(x) → map Returns a map containing the count of the
>   number of times each input value occurs.

Or it may exists from UDF to play with map on HQL, such as https://github.com/klout/brickhouse. I don't know it very much but you can give a try.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
select node,SUM(neighbour) 
    from #neighbourhood 
    group by node
```

Comment: I need the neighbour to frequency map. SUM wont do this. Sorry for the confusion. I have edited the question now.

Comment: Still your question is not clear?Tell me exactly what do you need